# “Invalid use of argument matchers” but I use matchers only

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I wish to test the following getRights method:

```
public GetProductRp getRights(String aaId, String bbId, String ccId) {
    GetProductRp rp = (GetProductRp) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(createRq(aaId, bbId, ccId));
    return rp;
}


private GetProductRq createRq(String aaId, String bbId, String ccId) {
    GetProductRq rq = new GetProductRq();

    GetProductRqBody body = new GetProductRqBody();

    body.setaaId(aaId);
    body.setbbId(bbId);
    body.setccId(ccId);

    rq.setBody(body);

    return rq;
}
```

This is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
public class ClassTest {

@Autowired
private Class rightClass;
@MockBean
private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

@Test
public void getRightsTest() throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    GetProductRp response = Helper.createProductRp("xx", "yy");

    Method mCreateRq = rightClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("createRq", String.class, String.class, String.class);
    mCreateRq.setAccessible(true);
    GetProductRq request = (GetProductRq) mCreateRq.invoke(rightClass, "12345678", "12345678", "1111");

    Mockito.when(webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request)).thenReturn(response);

    Mockito.when(rightClass.getRights(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(response);

    Assert.assertNotNull(response);
}
```

I receive the error provided in the short description above altough I only use Matchers (Mockito.anyString())....

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here could be that you are putting `@Autowired` on `private Class rightClass;` and you are trying to mock the method of it. If you want to mock the method then you should put `@MockBean` annotation as :

```
@MockBean 
private Class rightClass;
```

Comment: But I do not want to mock that class, I wish to use the original one.
By the way, I have other similar classes to test, and all of them are working fine. The only difference is that in those classes there is only one input parameter whish has to be mocked..

Comment: If you don't wish to mock it then why are you writing this Mockito.when(rightClass.getRights(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(response);
?